# While doing an event handling exercise why didn't I need to use the componentDidMount() method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to this and still in the process of learning the fundamentals of ReactJS. I have a question in regards to an exercise that I'm doing from a book.

In this exercise I am required to create an event handling component in which I have to use a state property, my question is that when I did the previous exercise I had to use the componentDidMount() method and on my current event handling exercise I did not require one. The code examples are shown below:

```
      var SecondCounter = React.createClass({

      //this is our getInitialState method. It initializes the value in our 
      //component. 
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          sec: 0
        };
      },
      //this is our timerTick function where we add an increment of one to 
      // display it as a second everytime setInterval funct gets called. 
      //this function calls setState to update our component

      timerTick: function() {
        this.setState({
          sec: this.state.sec + 1
        });
      },

      //This function calls our setInterval function after our component
      //renders
      componentDidMount: function() {
        setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);
      },

      //this.state displays the value of our state property
      render: function() {

        var myCompStyle = {
          color: "#66FFFF",
          fontSize: 50
        };

        var count = this.state.sec.toLocaleString();
        return (
              <h1 style={myCompStyle}>{count}</h1>
          );
      }
      /*Our component updates because whenever we call setState and update something
        in the state object, our component's render method gets automatically called.*/
    });
```

For this exercise it was a basic counter that used ReactJS' state methods. In this project I had to use all three APIs. I understand that the componentDidMount() method executes right after our component get rendered. What I assumed was that after the setState updates our sec prop our componentDidMount() method updates it in the UI.

Below is the current exercise that I'm doing:

```
      var CounterParent = React.createClass({
      //We know this component is going to change because it has an initial state
      //method. 
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          count: 0
        };
      },

      //This is our event handler function. This is basically what gets
      //called everytime our button gets clicked. 
      increase: function(e) {
        this.setState({
          count: this.state.count + 1
        });
      },

      render: function() {
        //remember a CSS objet property always ends a block of code with a 
        //semicolon.
        var backgroundStyle = {
            padding: 50,
            backgroundColor: "#FFC53A",
            width: 250,
            height: 100,
            borderRadius: 10,
            textAlign: "center"
        };

        var buttonStyle = {
          fontSize: "lem",
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          fontFamily: "sans-serif",
          color: "#333",
          fontWeight: "bold",
          lineHeight: "3px"
        };

        return (
          //This is where you add the count variable into your Counter2 display property.

          //Event Handling: You specify both the event you are listening for and the event
          //handler that will get called, all inside your markup. 
          <div style={backgroundStyle}>
            <Counter2 display={this.state.count}/>
            <button onClick={this.increase} style={buttonStyle}>+</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
  });
```

Notice that the componentDidMount() method was not there? Why didn't I need to use one in the event handling exercise?

Also the 1st projects purpose is like a timer. It just counts to seconds and never ends.

The 2nd project is a click counter. So every time I click on the button a count property updates. This exercise doesn't use the componentDidMount() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* lifecycle hooks in React.  You may use any of them if you have a need for them, but you will *frequently* ignore the vast majority of them.

A full list of these methods can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

The reason the `componentDidMount` hook was required in your first example was because you wanted to run a function when the component had mounted (thus the lifecycle method name).  That function (`setInterval`) is a core javascript method which starts a timer and then executes another function every N milliseconds.

Specifically;

```
setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);
```

Means "begin running `this.timerTick` every 1000 milliseconds (or every 1 second)".

Your second component simply has no need for anything to be triggered "on mount".  So the hook is, harmlessly, ignored.

Comment: So the first exercise needed it because after the component initialized and mounted it called the componentDidMount() method which called the setInterval() method thus creating an accumulation of seconds. I understand.

Comment: Yup, that's it!